# jQuery event is overwriting

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am facing a unknown problem and it is as below:

I have one link to open some popup

```
<a href="#" data-target="popup1" class=".pop-link">Link Here</a>
```

Now this is working fine, when i click on a link then popup is fired.

JS - I can not make changes to this event (Security reasons)

```
$(".pop-link").off("click").on("click", function (e) {
    <!-- Code to open popup -->
});
```

Now, i want to do one more event on click of `.pop-link`. and I added as below:

```
$(".pop-link").on("click", function (e) {
    console.log("Sdf");
});
```

With this my console.log works but then popup is not displayed.
Not sure why it is overwriting previous event. What can i do to have 2 events on same link?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I tried using `bind` and it is working now

```
$(".pop-link").bind("click", function (e) {
  console.log("Sdf");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created 2 click events using same class name. so jquery will execute last event.

To solve this you can add you second event code inside popup event code like this :

```
$(".pop-link").off("click").on("click", function (e) {
   <!-- Code to open popup -->
   console.log("Sdf");
});
```

Comment: i mentioned that i can not modify that event. Please see my answer

Comment: then you have to bind that event.